# filtering JSON stings array with NSPredicate and regular expression

Tags: objective-c, json, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

I have an `NSArray` containing `JSON` string like below.

```
[  
   {  
      "title":"find good book",
      "isCompleted":true
   },
   {  
      "title":"complete work",
      "isCompleted":false
   },
   {  
      "title":"check schedule",
      "isCompleted":false
   }
]
```

I want to find indexes of objects having "plet" value under "title" key. When I just simply used below `NSPredicate`, it returned every objects, because every `JSON` objects having "isCompleted" stings as a key.

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"plet"];
```

I don't want to convert `JSON` to `NSDictionary` object. And I don't use `[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:]`, because I am going to apply this predicate to `NSFetchedResultsController`. According to document, `NSPredicate` which is created by `[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:]` can't be used to NSFetchedResultsController.

So my question is, can I use Regular expression to solve this problem? I don't know much about regular expression. Could anyone give example for this?

Comment: Why not convert them into proper objects and then save objects into the CoreData, afterwards you will be able to use predicate with property directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use predicateWithBlock method for creating your predicate. Inside the block, check whether the dynamicVale contains the value to be searched.

Code:

```
NSArray *yourArray = ....;
NSString *searchText = ...;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary   * _Nonnull evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
    NSArray *dynamicVales = [evaluatedObject valueForKeyPath: @"dynamicVales.value"];
    return [dynamicVales containsObject:searchText];

}];

NSArray *filteredArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Copied from JhonyKutties answer. Enjoy coding :)